# What is the Birthstar of Goddess Bhoodevi?

Tags: goddess

Please let me know the birthstar of Goddess Bhoodevi Nachiyar. I have once heard that she is born under Revathi Nakshatra. I want to know because, my sister got an alliance and the boy belongs to Shravana Nakshatram.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Birth star of Goddess Bhudevi is Revathi (Meena raasi).

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE! Please support your answer with some sources from authentic scriptures etc. If you have any question to ask please ask it separately  by using "Ask Question" link.This place is only for answers.Also Visit Help section  to know more about this site.